# Fluent Nhibernate for ASP.Net/Winfoms Apps

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, data-access-layer

Hi is there good tutorial about using Fluent Nhibernate in asp.net/winforms application ?

I have read  article about Fluent Nhibernate and it much better look on Nhibenate which from xml to mapping class...

I will use FnH as My DataAccess Methodology..

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fluent nhibernate is not a data access layer by itself, I think you should read the introduction to fluent nhibernate : http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started